# RelaxNG (compact) validation

Tags: validation, basex, relaxng-compact

I have two RelaxNG file (*fileA.rnc* and *fileB.rnc*) within the Database. *fileA.rnc* is the main schema which has included *fileB.rnc* with syntax:

```
include "fileB.rnc"
```

I want to validate my XML input with *fileA.rnc* schema at the time of ingestion with the function `validate:rng-report()`. But, it seems that the Basex 8.6.4 is unable to resolve the include schema.

It gives me error:

```
[bxerr:BXVA0001] Validation failed: Resource "C:\Users\NAVIN~1.RAW\AppData\Local\Temp\fileB.rnc (The system cannot find the file specified)" not found.
```

It is looking included rnc in local drive instead of db. Is this a bug?  Or, I am doing anything wrong.

Please have a look and share your inputs.

Comment: If you create new questions, please always mention what happens exactly (do you get an error message? how does it look like? can you provide us with a little self-contained example? etc.).

Comment: Christian, I have added the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external Jing library is used for validating documents with RelaxNG, and Jing will try to include the referenced schema file. This is why your agenda files cannot be located if stored in the database. Instead, you'll have to move them to your local file system. If you still want to organize them in a central database instance, you can copy them from the database to a temporary file and delete them again after validation, all with the help of the File Module.